How to leverage the separable functions in MCMC sampling?
I'm considering the posterior of a parametric model via the Bayesian approach. More specificity, I have a parametric model $u(p_1,p_2, p_3) = u_1(p_1) \times u_2(p_2) \times u_3(p_3)$ and I want to study the posterior distributions of $\mathbf{p}= \{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ given some data $\mathcal {D}$. Hence Bayes' formula returns:
$$p(\mathbf{p}|D) = \frac{p(D|\mathbf{p})\times p(\mathbf{p})}{\text{evidence}}.$$
Suppose my prior $p(\mathbf{p})$ can be written as $p(p_1) \times p(p_2) \times p(p_3)$, my likelihood function is a Gaussian centered at the output of the model:$$p(D|\mathbf{p}) = \mathcal{N}(u(\mathbf{p}),\sigma^2)$$
Are there efficient sampling techniques to leverage the seperable structure of
$$u(p_1,p_2, p_3) = u_1(p_1) \times u_2(p_2) \times u_3(p_3)$$
Here is an example. Suppose we have 5 sampling points along each dimension, in total we have 125 points.
If $u(p_1,p_2, p_3)$
is not seperable, we may have to go through each data point in the 3 dimensional space. This can be challenging for high dimensional cases. However, if $u(p_1,p_2, p_3)$ seperable, we can just go through each 1D domain and then use tensor product to compute ue to the seperation of varible, we can use tensor product to compute u(p1,p2,p3)

I do not understand the notation $\mathcal{N}(u(\mathbf{p},\sigma^2))$ since $u(\cdots)$ is supposed to be a density. I also fail to see why a tensor should appear in this picture.

Thanks Xi'an. I already changed the typo into $\mathcal{N}(u(\mathbf{p}),\sigma^2)$. The tensor will come into picture if we have multiple samples for $p_1, p_2, p_3$. Due to the seperation of varible, we can use tensor product to compute $u(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ for all the samples. I think a better statement should be "how to leverage the seperable structure of $u(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ . If $u$ is not seperable, we may have to go through each data point in the 3 dimensional space. But since it's seperable, we can just go through each 1D domain and then use tensor product to compute.
